# override virtual with Xunit ICLassFixture WebAppliationFactory Integration Testing

Tags: c#, polymorphism, integration-testing, xunit

I don't work with xunit very often and am trying to understand how to go about overriding a method in my webAppliationFactory class that gets inherited in my fixture. I am needing to mock a service in my startup class and it would be awesome if I could override the response per class/test. I don't really want to get into a debate on why I want to mock a service in an integration test. I just want to.

My injection setup

```
public class CreateWebAppFactory<TStartup>
: WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class 
{
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        var svc = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(INeedToMockThis));
        services.Remove(svc);
        var svcMock= new Mock<INeedToMockThis> ();
        svcMock.Setup(x => x.Foo(It.IsAny<long> ()))
            .ReturnsAsync(TheMethodIwantToOverride()); <-- How can I manage this? 
        services.AddScoped(x => svcMock.Object);
        ...
    }
protected virtual int TheMethodIwantToOverride()
 {
return 1;
}
```

My test

```
 public class GivenSomethingNeedsToBeTested: IClassFixture<CreateWebAppFactory<Startup>>
 
 private readonly CreateWebAppFactory<Startup> _factory;
 private HttpClient _client;

 public GivenSomethingNeedsToBeTested(CreateWebAppFactory<Startup> factory)
{
    _factory = factory;
    _client = factory.CreateClient();
}

public override int TheMethodIwantToOverride() <-- This is not available to me to use.. 
{
    return 2; 
}
```

I hope this explanation is sufficient? Is this not possible?